# MobileVLCKit for iOS failing to build

Tags: compilation, ios9, libvlc, libtool-xcode

I am cloning **MobileVLCKit.framework** for my project.I have to make some minor tweaks to source, i cannot use a ready made build.

**I am following the steps given at :** http://thelazycoder.com/uncategorized/libmobilevlc

But, I am getting error

```
** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
    Libtool build/MobileVLCKit.build/Debug-iphoneos/MobileVLCKit.build/Objects-normal/arm64/libMobileVLCKit.a normal arm64
    Libtool build/MobileVLCKit.build/Debug-iphoneos/MobileVLCKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/libMobileVLCKit.a normal armv7
    Libtool build/MobileVLCKit.build/Debug-iphoneos/MobileVLCKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/libMobileVLCKit.a normal
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/rajankumartiwari/Desktop/20/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7s/lib/libvlc.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/rajankumartiwari/Desktop/20/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7s/lib/libvlccore.a (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: The error coming because we need set up our mac system with home-brew. Which i had not done. After doing so, problem was solved.